# is "all" implied in a list?

Tags: grammar, lists, descriptive-grammar

If I have a list that begins with:

"Cars He Wants to Buy"

Is it implied that that list contains ALL the cars he wants to buy?  Or is it implied that it is just some?

My thought was that an "all" is implied, but I wanted to make sure "Cars He Wants to Buy" is clear enough.

Comment: No, it does not say: All the cars he wants to buy.

Comment: What if it was "The Cars He Wants to Buy"

Answer (score 1):

"Cars he wants to buy" does not say whether the list that follows is exhaustive (complete), or not, but adding 'the' at the start ("the cars he wants to buy") changes the meaning and says that the list is complete.